# Issues with previous button

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, pagination

I am using below lines of code for generating page numbers for pagination which I have created as custom control. I have added repeater control in it. I am populating repeater with page numbers by using PopulatePager() method. 
I have added two button, one for next set of page numbers and second for previous set of page numbers. Actually I have 49 total page numbers, it does not look good to show all page numbers in it. Now we have to show only set of 5 numbers at a time like << 1 2 3 4 5 >>. when user will click on >> button then it will be like << 6 7 8 9 10 >> ... so on. I have created two events lnknext_Click() and lnkprev_Click().

Next button is working perfectly but previous button is not working properly.
for e.g  if we are at << 22 23 24 25 26 >> then clicking on << button, it will display << 16 17 18 19 20 21 >> then again clicking on it displays << 1 2 3 4 5 >> instead of << 10 11 12 13 14 15 >>... 
Please help me!!!

```
       public void PopulatePager()
       {
        int recordCount = TotalPages;
        if (PageSizeChanged != null)
        {
            HiddenField hd = new HiddenField();

            int current;
            current = PageIndex;
            int pre;
            int Next;
            double dblPageCount = (double)((decimal)recordCount / decimal.Parse(ddlPageSize.SelectedValue));
            int pageCount = TotalPages;

            List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
            if (pageCount > 0)
            {
                //pages.Add(new ListItem("First", "1", PageIndex > 1));
                current = PageIndex;
                pre = --PageIndex;
                PageIndex = current;

                // pages.Add(new ListItem("Previous", pre.ToString(), PageIndex > 1));

                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    if (i <= 5)
                    {
                        pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
                    }
                }
                int currentPage = PageIndex;
                Next = ++PageIndex;
                PageIndex = currentPage;
                //  pages.Add(new ListItem("Next", Next.ToString(), PageIndex < pageCount));
                //  pages.Add(new ListItem("Last", pageCount.ToString(), PageIndex < pageCount));

                hd.Value = (pre.ToString());


            }
            if (Session["pages"] != null)
            {
                rptPager.DataSource = Session["pages"];
                rptPager.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                rptPager.DataSource = pages;
                rptPager.DataBind();
            }

            Session["lastnumber"] = 5;
            Session["pagecount"] = pageCount;
            Session["orignalpages"] = pages;

        }
    }

    protected void lnkprev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
        int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
        int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
        if (lastnumber > pagecount)
        {
            Session["lastnumber"] = pagecount - 5;
            lastnumber = pagecount - 5;
            Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
            Session["orignalpages"] = pages;

        }
        else
        {

            Session["lastnumber"] = 1;
            lastnumber = 1;
            Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
            Session["orignalpages"] = pages;
        }

        int limit = lastnumber + 5;
        for (int i = lastnumber; i <= pagecount; i++)
        {
            if (i <= limit && i > 0)
            {
                pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
            }
            else
            {
                rptPager.DataSource = Session["orignalpages"];
                rptPager.DataBind();
            }
        }
        Session["lastnumber"] = limit;
        Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;

        Session["pages"] = pages;

        rptPager.DataSource = pages;
        rptPager.DataBind();
    }
    protected void lnknext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
        int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
        int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
        if (lastnumber > pagecount)
        {
            Session["lastnumber"] = 1;
            lastnumber = 1;
            Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
            Session["orignalpages"] = pages;

        }


        int limit = lastnumber + 4;
        for (int i = lastnumber; i <= pagecount; i++)
        {
            if (i <= limit)
            {
                pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
            }
            else
            {
                rptPager.DataSource = Session["orignalpages"];
                rptPager.DataBind();
            }
            Session["lastnumber"] = limit;
            Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;

            Session["pages"] = pages;

            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there something wrong with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "DataTable" javascript functionality for this problem. Please refer https://www.datatables.net/.

In this you just need to give your table Id in below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer... i m getting all the values related to pagination via stored procedures dynamically. will it work for me